# java communication with Pascal application Is it Possible

Tags: java, pascal

I have been asked by someone to implement communication between a Java application and a Pascal application. I have very little knowledge of Pascal. Is it possible? If so, can someone provide some guidance? Currently I am clueless at this point.

Comment: Consider looking into web services.  These can be made implementation agnostic.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure this is possible.

In case if you simply need to use a set of functions implemented on Pascal you can use [JNI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) with the same way as C. I.e. create a DLL for Windows or shared library for UNIX using Pascal with the JNI specific function names.
You can use [pas2jni](http://wiki.freepascal.org/pas2jni) instead of javac -h (or javah) or make your work simpler with [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) library

If you interested with multi-process integration, i.e. you have one app written on Java and another app written on Pascal you can use SOAP or REST API.

- To implementing SOAP on Pascal you can use
  [Web Service Toolkit](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit)
- To implement REST on Pascal you can use
  [mORMot](https://synopse.info/forum/index.php) toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

- File system (cross file communications). i.e. you have one shared file which can be read/written by both apps
- Network (SOAP/REST)